# While trying to load a file into a table MySQL does not take in the full path, leaves out the file name and then says no such file

Tags: php, mysql, file-io, load

I am using EasyPHP on windows.

CODE:

```
    $ffname = realpath("db\application.dat");

    $query = "
    LOAD DATA INFILE LOCAL '$ffname'
    INTO TABLE $tablename
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\\n'
    (fields...)";

$conn->query($query);
```

ERROR:

> failed : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to
>   use near 'LOCAL 'C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC11\data\localweb\projects\' at line 1

ECHO OF QUERY:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE LOCAL 'C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC11\data\localweb\projects\projectname\db\file.dat' INTO TABLE application FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' (some fields here)
```

Comment: You have to "shell escape" that path. Otherwise it indeed violates the sql syntax. This is a very common issue with the stupid naming convention MS-Windows systems still use. Characters like `:`, `\\ ` and ` ` have to be escaped, maybe even the `(` and `)`.

Comment: @arkascha I used **escapeshellarg()** and **addslashes()** to no avail.

Comment: You mean you get exactly the same error? Could you add your attempted query to the question please? Thanks!

Comment: Ah, sorry, I just see: the issue is another one: you scrambled the order of arguments. Actually the error message states that quite clearly. Change `LOAD DATA INFILE LOCAL` to `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE`... For such things it always makes sense to take a look into the documentation to check the exact syntax...